# How to add different events to different divs

Tags: jquery, events, dom

When using `document.getElementsByTagName('div')` you get an array of the div nodes, which can be used in a loop to assign different events to different divs.

How can I do this with jQuery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the same in the jquery:

```
$('div').each(function() {
    if ($(this).attr('id') == '1')
       $(this).click(function() { // handler for first div });

    if ($(this).attr('id') == '2')
       $(this).click(function() { // handler for second div });\

    ...
});
```

Answer (score 5):

To do that in jQuery use:

```
$("div").each(function () {
    // 'this' is the div
});
```

This is the same as:

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div'),
    i,
    len,
    div;

for (i = 0, len = divs.length; i < len; i++) {
    div = divs[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add the name into jQuery's selector...

> $("tag-name-here")

You can then use `.each`, however for performance I prefer to use a good old Javascript for loop.

This may help: http://api.jquery.com/each/ & http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/06/javascript-for-loop-vs-jquery-each.html

Answer (score 0):

`$('div')`

This will create a jQuery collection of DIVs [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var divs = jQuery('div');

divs.each(function(){
     $(this).DoSomeThing();

     // $(this) refers to a div
});
```